# Значение select неизменно, даже после визуального изменения

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть периоды (месяц + год) и есть 2 select элемента для них. В зависимости от выбранного года - периоды фильтруются так, чтобы остались только те периоды, которые попадают в интервал. Суть проблемы: после фильтрации значения прокидываются в select'ы и визуально все на месте, но при изменении значения - реальные данные уходящие на сервер не изменяются. Предположим - отфильтровал за 2020 год, попали периоды с января по декабрь 2020, я выбираю в поле с: январь 2020, по: декабрь 2020 и на сервер улетает январь - январь, хотя визуально значение изменено на декабрь. Весь скрипт прилагаю.

```js
$(document).change(function () {
    var yearFrom = $('select[id="yearReportFrom"]').val();
    var yearTo = $('select[id="yearReportTo"]').val();
    var selectFrom =  $('select[id="periodsReportFrom"]');
    var selectTo =  $('select[id="periodsReportTo"]');
    filterPeriodsInSelect(yearFrom, yearTo, selectFrom, selectTo);
    if (yearFrom < 2020 || yearTo < 2020) {
        $('select[id="periodsReportFrom"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('select[id="periodsReportTo"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('select[id="periodsReportFrom"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('select[id="periodsReportTo"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});

function filterPeriodsInSelect(yearFrom, yearTo, selectFrom, selectTo) {
    if (yearFrom === yearTo) {
        var filteredPeriods = filterPeriodsByYear(allPeriods, yearFrom.toString());
        setPeriodsToSelect(selectFrom, filteredPeriods);
        setPeriodsToSelect(selectTo, filteredPeriods);
    } else {
        setPeriodsToSelect(selectFrom, allPeriods);
        setPeriodsToSelect(selectTo, allPeriods);
    }
}

function filterPeriodsByYear(periods, year) {
    var filteredPeriods = [];

    for (const period of periods) {
        if (period.label.includes(year))
            filteredPeriods.push(period);
    }

    return filteredPeriods;
}

function setPeriodsToSelect(select, periods) {
    select.empty();

    $.each(periods, function(key,value) {
        select.append($("<option></option>")
            .attr("value", value.value).text(value.label));
    });
```

Comment: Ваш код не запускается.

Comment: это же фрагмент скрипта, а не целая страница со скриптом. Ничего удивительного, что он отдельно не запускается.